# Task Scheduler in Spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

I am using spring scheduler tasks for calling a method in class after fixed interval like below

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="scheduler">
<task:scheduled ref="processScheduledJobs" method="init" fixed-delay=5000/>
```

Once the scheduler triggers the init method. init method is going to use the thread pool executor to execute all the jobs in the queue.

```
<bean id="processScheduledJobs" class="XXXX.VV.ProcessScheduledJobs">
 <property name="pool" ref="jobExecutorService"" />
</bean>

<bean id="scheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="threadFactory">
      <bean class="XXX..VVV.NamingThreadFactory">
           <constructor-arg value="thread" />
      </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="16" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="64" />
  <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="4" />
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="512" />
</bean>
```

Questions:
is the initial thread which executed the init method wait till all the processing (done by executor service by spawning new threads) in the init method is finished?

Is the pool size attribute for scheduler task is only used for triggering the tasks not for executing or processing the logic inside the triggered task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread belonging to `scheduler` will submit all jobs to `jobExecutorService`. Up to 64 of them will begin executing immediately, the rest, up to 512 will end up in queue. As soon as all are submitted - not executed - the init method will exit. This shouldn't take longer than mere milliseconds.

If `scheduler` is not the same as `jobExecutorService` - I can't tell this since part of your xml is missing - its threads won't be used for execution of jobs logic.

Comment: thanks.. update for typo - scheduler is the same what is mentioned above.. with you answere its clear that my main thread will exit once its submit all the jobs. since we have defined fixed delay so another thread should be executed again after the mention time. Right? In yes, in that case how will scheduler behave. will there be a new instance or will it use the same instance and the add the jobs to it.

Comment: It will keep on reusing `scheduler` bean, the same 64 threads will be doing their work with new jobs submitted every 5 seconds.